# Does ruby use stack for memory management?

Tags: ruby, memory-management

It is more of a hypothetical question, but I was eagerly searching for the answer in web for a while.

I read that programming languages uses heap for storing references and stack for values / data. In ruby everything is an object and we may have to save only references, does ruby use stack for memory management or only heap?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Things you read about one programming language are not necessarily true (or even applicable) for any other programming language.

Comment: Thanks Greg. Well if there is no straight forward answers, any references that can guide me to understand these will be useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That probably depends on the version of Ruby you're talking about. The MRI 1.8.x line used the heap. See [Engine Yard blog post](https://www.engineyard.com/blog/mri-memory-allocation-a-primer-for-developers) for more information.

Comment: Thanks dj2, I wasn't aware that the memory management architecture will change based on the version of ruby.

Comment: that link is dead now :(

Comment: The link is fixed now. Thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 2):

It might be a little late but this article about garbage collection for ruby 2.0 should help anyone looking to understand it better.

http://patshaughnessy.net/2012/3/23/why-you-should-be-excited-about-garbage-collection-in-ruby-2-0